# EndDate and StartDate on Canceled WorkOrders

Tags: field-service-lightning, work-order, work-order-status

WorkOrders have a set of standard fields called 
`StartDate` and `EndDate`.  According to the [SOAP API documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_workorder.htm), they are defined as such:

> **StartDate**: The date when the work order goes into effect.
>
> For example, you can create a quick action that sets the StartDate to the date when the Status changes to In Progress
>
> **EndDate**: The date when the work order is completed.
>
> For example, you can create a quick action that sets the EndDate to 365 days after the StartDate.

There is one WorkOrder status category that sort of defies this: "Canceled".

If a WorkOrder is canceled, according to these rules, I would expect to see a null EndDate, and probably a null StartDate.  That is how my current code works, but I am newly interested in the date a WO was Canceled.  I am considering recording this in EndDate.

Will I regret this decision?

What is actually being done in the field?  Are there common integrations that rely on a particular definition of these fields so that I'll regret my choices here?

#### Aside

Those definitions presented in the documentation don't seem to be related to one another, nor the field's natural names, nor to the examples given.  Very odd.